# "Отдавать отчет"

Tags: фразеология

Как правильно говорить: "отдавать отчет своим действиям" или "...в своих действиях"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В русском языке есть выражение "отдавать себе отчет". Поэтому, в любом случае, правильно будет "отдавать (себе) отчет в чем-то"